# How to parse an JSONObject containing key-value-pairs?

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, retrofit2, dto

At First: I know the JSON should contain a array with key-value-Pairs, but it's not my API so I can't change it.

This is what the response looks like:

```
{
    "translations": {
        "my.key.nr.0": "Value 0",
        "my.key.nr.1": "Value 1",
        "my.key.nr.2": "Value 2",
        "my.key.nr.3": "Value 3",
    },
    "hash": "123xyz",
    "length": 3,
    "language": "de"
}
```

And this is my DTO so far:

```
data class TranslationsDto(
    val translations: ??????????, // <-- dont't know what to use here
    val hash: String?,
    val length: Int?,
    val language: String?
)
```

Finally, here's my Problem:

I need to parse the response (at least Retrofit should parse the response) to a DTO I can use in my App. If the value of `translations` would be a array there would be no problem but I can't get it how to parse this JSON structure.

Maybe anyone of you have some ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

damn... sometimes I'm pretty blind after all...

Just use `Map<String,String>` :

```
data class TranslationsDto(
    val translations: Map<String,String>?,
    val hash: String?,
    val length: Int?,
    val language: String?
)
```